I tried to deploy on Remix but getting Gas Estimation error and I don't know the reason
Good people of Blockchain, Hello. I wrote a simple smart contract but having a hard time deploying it on Remix. I will try to deploy it on Anvil too since I work with Foundry but for a quick test, I wanted to try Remix. When I used the Remix debugger, it showed me on the 8th line of priceConverter contract, there was a problem and I could not understand what is it and why is it happening. I tried to play around with constructor to make sure I got it right and the constructor was not the problem. I know the address of priceFeed is valid because I get it from the chain link price feed site. I kinda duplicate my piceConverter from another project that worked well. I cannot find the issue. I would be grateful if you help me. This is my first attempt to try to make my first smart contract start to finish by myself, which means I would really appreciate your help.
Here is my Distributor contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import {PriceConverter} from "./PriceConverter.sol";


////////////////////
// Errors        //
//////////////////
error Distributor__NotOwner();
error Distributor__NotEnoughTimeHasPassed();
error Distributor__NoFundsToDistribute();
error Distributor__InsufficientFunds();
error Distributor__DuplicateAddress();
error Distributor__MismatchedArrays();

///////////////////////////////
// Interfaces, Libraries, Contracts //
///////////////////////////////
contract Distributor {
    //////////////////////
    // State Variables //
    ////////////////////
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    uint256 public lastReceivedTimestamp;
    uint256 public distributeCallTimestamp;
    uint256 public constant DELAY_FOR_RECEIVE = 2 minutes;
    AggregatorV3Interface private s_priceFeed;
    using PriceConverter for uint256;
    uint256 public totalBalance = address(this).balance;
    uint256 public totalBalanceInUsd = totalBalance.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed);

    ////////////////////
    // Events        //
    //////////////////
    event FundsReceived(uint256 indexed amount);
    event DelayStarted();
    event DistributionEnded(address[] _receivers, uint256[] _amounts);
    event CoinTransfer(address indexed receiver, uint256 amount);
    event TokenTransfer(address indexed receiver, uint256 amount, address token);

    ////////////////////
    // Modifiers     //
    //////////////////
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (owner != msg.sender) revert Distributor__NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    /////////////////////
    // Constructor    //
    ///////////////////
    constructor(address priceFeed)  {
    owner = msg.sender;
    s_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeed);
}

    ///////////////////////
    // Receive Function //
    /////////////////////
    receive() external payable {
        emit FundsReceived(address(this).balance);
        lastReceivedTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        emit DelayStarted();
    }

    ////////////////////////
    // External Functions //
    ////////////////////////
    function distributor(address[] memory _receivers, uint256[] memory _amounts) external onlyOwner {
        if (_receivers.length != _amounts.length) revert Distributor__MismatchedArrays();
        if (block.timestamp < lastReceivedTimestamp + DELAY_FOR_RECEIVE) revert Distributor__NotEnoughTimeHasPassed();

        uint256 totalAmountInWei = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _amounts.length; i++) {
            uint256 amountInWei = _amounts[i].getConversionRate(s_priceFeed);
            totalAmountInWei += amountInWei;
            balances[_receivers[i]] += amountInWei;
        }

        if (address(this).balance < totalAmountInWei) revert Distributor__InsufficientFunds();

        // Effects

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            address payable receiver = payable(_receivers[i]);
            uint256 amountInWei = _amounts[i].getConversionRate(s_priceFeed);
            receiver.transfer(amountInWei);
            emit CoinTransfer(receiver, amountInWei);
        }

        emit DistributionEnded(_receivers, _amounts);
    }

    function distributorTokens(IERC20 token, address[] memory _receivers, uint256[] memory _amounts)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        if (_receivers.length != _amounts.length) revert Distributor__MismatchedArrays();
        if (block.timestamp < lastReceivedTimestamp + DELAY_FOR_RECEIVE) revert Distributor__NotEnoughTimeHasPassed();

        uint256 totalAmount = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _amounts.length; i++) {
            totalAmount += _amounts[i];
        }

        uint256 contractBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        if (contractBalance < totalAmount) revert Distributor__InsufficientFunds();

        // Effects
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            address receiver = _receivers[i];
            if (balances[receiver] != 0) revert Distributor__DuplicateAddress();
            balances[receiver] += _amounts[i];
            emit TokenTransfer(receiver, _amounts[i], address(token));
        }

        // Interactions
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            token.transfer(_receivers[i], _amounts[i]);
        }

        emit DistributionEnded(_receivers, _amounts);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////
    // Internal & Private Functions //
    ////////////////////////////////
    function convertSUDTToWei(uint256 amount) internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = s_priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 maticToUSDT = uint256(price);
        return (amount * 1e18) / maticToUSDT; // Convert SUDT to Wei
    }


    ////////////////////////////////
    // External & Public View & Pure Functions //
    ////////////////////////////////
    function getContractBalance(IERC20 token) external view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function getEtherBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPriceFeed() public view returns (AggregatorV3Interface) {
        return s_priceFeed;
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns(uint256){
        return AggregatorV3Interface(0x0A6513e40db6EB1b165753AD52E80663aeA50545).version();
    }
}

this is my price converter contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

library PriceConverter {
    function getPrice(AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed) internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(price * 1e10); // Adjusting decimals
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 amount, AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 price = getPrice(priceFeed);
        return (amount * 1e18) / price; // Convert amount to Wei
    }
}

and this is the error I get when trying to deploy my contract on Remix injected meta mask environment(I have added the amoy network to my meta mask and the address I put is for a usdt/usd on polygon/amoy network):

creation of Distributor pending...
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: Distributor.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...50545logs: 0hash: 0x932...6447b
status  0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0x932c162752eed08b49e4eef202b482e138770aebf7e30fe494f9344bae16447b
block hash  0xcd7e4068647c1e7d408f7512328534cbf8e765d64792409d99008396c1c7e6ad
block number    2
contract address    0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  Distributor.(constructor)
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    173405 gas 
execution cost  7399 gas 
input   0x608...50545
decoded input   {
    "address priceFeed": "0x0A6513e40db6EB1b165753AD52E80663aeA50545"
}
decoded output   - 
logs    []
creation of Distributor errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.


The price feed address that you’ve got from Chainlink docs is of an actual testnet or mainnet, so that is not supposed to work with local Remix VM environment.
For working with local environment like Remix VM or Foundry Anvil node, you should deploy the mock price feed contract like MockV3Aggregator, and use the address of the same while deploying your Distributor contract.
Also, in your Distributor contract, you're calling the getConversionRate function of the PriceConverter library in the contract body, outside any specific function. This is not allowed in Solidity. Instead, library functions must be called within a contract function.
And, I can see, you're not using totalBalanceInUsd variable anywhere in your contract, so you can just get rid of those two lines:
u̶i̶n̶t̶2̶5̶6̶ p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ t̶o̶t̶a̶l̶B̶a̶l̶a̶n̶c̶e̶ =̶ a̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶)̶.b̶a̶l̶a̶n̶c̶e̶;̶
u̶i̶n̶t̶2̶5̶6̶ p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ t̶o̶t̶a̶l̶B̶a̶l̶a̶n̶c̶e̶I̶n̶U̶s̶d̶ =̶ t̶o̶t̶a̶l̶B̶a̶l̶a̶n̶c̶e̶.g̶e̶t̶C̶o̶n̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶R̶a̶t̶e̶(̶s̶_̶p̶r̶i̶c̶e̶F̶e̶e̶d̶)̶;̶

After removing them (or moving them to a function, if required), then the contract can be deployed sucessfully.

Hi friend, thanks for your response, the problem is that when I use an injected meta mask environment, I still get the same error, but thanks for mentioning it, I will correct my question

No worries, @HessamedeanAghajanlou. I would recommend you to share your code as a gist, so that, I can help you debug the same.

Dear Syed Asad, I think you can see it with this link https://gist.github.com/Hessamedean/1426ecc0a411533475bdc203422db538
and sorry about the late response I was really busy yesterday. If you have the time to check my project, I would be really grateful for your help.

I think the problem is that you multiply price by 1e10 to adjust the decimals, but this will overflow if price exceeds MAX_INT256 / 1e10.
The correct way to adjust decimals is to divide by 10 ** priceFeed.decimals()
function getPrice(AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed) internal view returns (uint256) {
    (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();
    return uint256(price) * 10**(18 - decimals); // Adjusting decimals

The function now correctly scales price to decimal places, regardless of how many decimal places the price source returns.
Also note that in the Distributor constructor you do not initialize totalBalanceInUsd. This may cause an error the first time you call functions that use totalBalanceInUsd, as it will be 0. You can try like this:
constructor(address priceFeed) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    s_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeed);
    totalBalanceInUsd = totalBalance.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed);
}

Write later how it turned out for you, OK?

Hello dear friend Aleksander, I have made the recommended changes but still got the same error "The gas estimation failed". about the decimals, thank you for bringing my attention to it, I am not really good with the solidity math yet. thanks again for your help, I tried to compile it but still hasn't worked.

I'm sorry that this didn't help you, but I also don't know how else to approach this problem. Try again to send the complete smart contract that you have obtained. It is quite possible that something could have been missed...

So, Finally, I did manage to deploy my contract after reviewing that I was using too many events in my contract that absolutely were not necessary. It may not be truly correct but after commenting out the events, my transaction went through and my contract deployed.
it's now something like this:
    ////////////////////
    // Events        //
    //////////////////
    // event FundsReceived(uint256 indexed amount);
    // event DelayStarted();
    // event DistributionEnded(address[] _receivers, uint256[] _amounts);
    // event CoinTransfer(address indexed receiver, uint256 amount);
    // event TokenTransfer(address indexed receiver, uint256 amount, address token);

 receive() external payable {
        // emit FundsReceived(address(this).balance);
        // lastReceivedTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        // emit DelayStarted();
    }

it's now something like this and for sure, at the end these lines will all be deleted.

Actually, it's not due to the events, but due to the calling of library function directly inside the contract body (i.e., outside any specific function). I've edited my answer by adding the explanation for the same.

Dear SYED ASAD, thank you again for sharing your knowledge. You are completely right. I did bring back the events, and my contract was deployed. I think the problem was with those two lines that I wasn't using in any function and also one of them was calling the library function outside of any function. Again Thank you for your guidance.

You’re welcome, @HessamedeanAghajanlou. Happy coding!
